# Mongodb aggregation multiple groups per document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using the mongodb aggregation framework for some analyses and I am stuck on this particulare one.

In english, I am trying to run the following query:

"Find the average 5 day count over a given time range."

So given a dataset that looks like this:

```
{
    :_id => BSONID,
    :date => ISO(DATE),
    :count => 3
},
{
    :_id => BSONID,
    :date => ISO(DATE),
    :count => 2
},
{
    :_id => BSONID,
    :date => ISO(DATE),
    :count => 9
}
...
```

I want a result:

```
[
{:_id => "2014-145", :five_day_average_count => 3},#this is the average count from 2014-145 through 2014-149
{:_id => "2014-146", :five_day_average_count => 6},#this is the average count from 2014-146 through 2014-150
{:_id => "2014-147", :five_day_average_count => 4},#this is the average count from 2014-147 through 2014-151
...
]
```

Where the _id is the $year and $dayOfYear (this can be achieved with $concat).

I am perfectly capable of $group'ing the data into groups of length 5 days. The difficulty is in the fact that a single data point will fall into 5 groups at once. Now I COULD run 5 aggregate queries, each with a separate start day of the grouping, but I would prefer to run a single query to save time.

I sincerely hope that I am being silly and a simple solution will be posted.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple or straightforward way to do this with one aggregation query. The trouble is that you want one document to group into multiple groups and this is not how `$group` works. Given that an aggregation for one 5-day average should hit just 5 documents, each aggregation should be very fast so I wouldn't be too concerned with running multiple.

Comment: I would agree with you, except there is not just one document per day, there are potentially hundreds or thousands, and I may not be asking for 5 days, but 100. It may be that I need to make a new data structure and use multiple queries. I will swallow that pill if nobody posts a clever solution soon.

Comment: Yes, use an alternate data form. It's very easy to accumulate statistics like these as part of inserts/updates so that the time-averaged cost of computing them is very, very low and querying is simply a look-up. I'd love to see a clever solution but, while I can't prove it, I don't think one exists.